# pandas generate range of dates in Unix Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, unix-timestamp

The dataframe I am working with contains historical stock prices and looks like this :

```
    timestamp   open        high        low       close      volume
0   1609459200  20830.70    21243.95    20830.7   21127.60   1663
1   1609718400  21288.00    21300.00    21065.0   21154.65   3043
2   1609804800  21154.65    21899.00    21011.0   21594.20   3048
...
```

The data is for January 1, 4 and 5 2021 and there are no rows for 2nd and 3rd of January as these are Saturdays and Sundays.

I wish to reindex this dataframe so that I can have these dates as well in my dataframe with forward filled data.

I have found `dti = pandas.date_range("2021-01-01", periods=3, freq="D")` which generates dates but not as unix second timestamps.
`DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')`

What is the easiest way to generate unix timestamps such as `1609459200`  using pandas.